# UX best practice for banking application

Tags: user-behavior

In a banking application, are there any negatives of showing the mini statement with the available balance?

Comment: Why do you want to show the statement? What does the statement contain? What good do you think it will do to the users? What negatives you think there would be?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done any research on user behavior for banking sites but I will mention this, **there is no downside of showing information (in short) relevant to the context**.

When I log into my Netbanking account (other than when actually doing transactions), I expect to see my balance, account number (in case of multiple accounts linked to the same id) and my last latest transactions. Most times when I log in, it is to either add a beneficiary, or to check my statement or to do other transactions.

Keep in mind that online banking is a very information sensitive application hence keeping the user informed at all times is a very good practice. Given that the use of passbooks has gone down, showing a mini statement is always good if the user wants to get a quick overview.

Comment: not sure about `no downside of showing information relevant to the context` - unless you define it in a way that excludes `The password you have typed is wrong, did you mean "MySecret123"?`

Comment: I can't see how this information relevant to the user? The "The password you typed is wrong" is definitely useful but how does this translate to this question which is clearly asking about a banking application and showing related info?

Comment: just an example how your suggested rule of thumb can be very very wrong.. i don't thing there exists any feature completely without downsides